# Display Chinese text in activities

Tags: android

I want to write Chinese text in activities but when i run the program i am getting error.

How to write Chinese text in activities? And We need to import any other files???

Comment: u have .ttf  file in asserts folder.

Answer (score 0):

Just use UNICODE characters in it: [UNICODE characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters)

Good luck:)